# Callback within a promise within a class?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have a class that I use to load external resources via an XMLHttpRequest (this is for WebGL) so I'm loading models, shaders etc. My plan was to put a loading display up whilst it did all these requests and then when it's finally complete I want it to run a callback function from the original function that created it. However, I'm getting strange results when I try to run that call back (such as it has no access of any of the objects within the class that did the loading).

I can get around this problem by passing "this" into the loading class and then doing

```
self = this; 
promise(self.callback());
```

but I'd much rather specify the function that I want it to callback to after its done the loading. Does anyone know if this can be done? My code looks like this:

**Main Class**

```
this.loadingClass = new LoadingClass(this.LoadingComplete, resources);

Main.prototype.LoadingComplete = function()
{
    // Returns undefined if i specify the callback function instead of just "this"
    console.log(this.loadingClass.anyOfTheMembersOfThisClass);
}
```

**Loading Class**

```
LoadingClass = function(callback, resources) {

  ..

        Promise.all(resources).then(function(loadedResources)
        {
            ..
            callback();

        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the function object as

```
(this.LoadingComplete, resources)
```

the object to which it was bound, will not be passed. So, only the function object `LoadingComplete` is passed to `LoadingClass` and when it is invoked as

```
callback()
```

the `this` value will be `undefined` (in strict mode).

To fix this,

- you need to bind the `this` object, like this

  ```
  new LoadingClass(this.LoadingComplete.bind(this), resources)
  ```
- if your environment supports ES2015's Arrow functions

  ```
  new LoadingClass(() => this.LoadingComplete(), resources);
  ```

In both these cases, when the `LoadingComplete` is invoked from `LoadingClass`, the `this` will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

You are detouching callback (read about ["this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) function from the root object, so of course it loses context. Specify bindingContext explicitly with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
this.loadingClass = new LoadingClass(this.LoadingComplete.bind(this), resources);
```